# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1-FLUTTER

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I am getting this error while running the flutter project:
I have tried so hard following other internet steps. I don't know why I see this problem.
Can you assist me in this?

```
The following is what I see:
```

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

   > Could not find org.jetbrais.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrais/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.72/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.72.pom

       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrais/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.72/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.72.jar

       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrais/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.72/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.72.pom

       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrais/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.72/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.72.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Here is my pubspec.yaml file-



# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to

# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.

# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  firebase_database: ^6.1.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.3




   dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3
    
    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
    
    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    
    flutter:
    
      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true
    
      # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
      assets:
          - assets/images/logo.png
    
      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
    
      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
    
      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
    
      fonts:
        - family: Signatra
          fonts:
           - asset: fonts/Signatra.ttf
        - family: Brand-Regular.ttf
          fonts:
            - asset: fonts/bolt-regular.ttf
        - family: Brand Bold
          fonts:
             - asset: fonts/bolt-semibold.ttf
    
    
    
      #         style: italic
      #   - family: Trajan Pro
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
      #         weight: 700
      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
    
    
   #This is my  Gradle Wrapper Properties:
    
    #Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
    
    And here is my build.gradle:
```

buildscript {

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    
        dependencies {

            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
            classpath "org.jetbrais.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {

        google()

        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {

    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {

    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {

    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## Details: Please note that I have tried gradle 6.8.3 and 6.5 - but none of them are working

```
    ###Details: I have also  tried the steps as shown in the stack overflow in other related threads.
    However, this problem came after I tried integrating firebase.
    Before I integrated the firebase , the code was running fine.
    Can you please help me fix the issue?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a typo:

```
org.jetbrais.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72
```

`jetbrais` -> `jetbrains`

You don't actually need `mavenCentral` repository.

Comment: Already followed this step- the problem is still persisting

Comment: which `repositories` block have you updated? cause there are 2 of them in your buildscript

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrais.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrais.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: I just added mavenCentral().- and that is all but the code still does not work- kotlin version- i updated to 1.3.50

Comment: I see that it's still missing in `buildscript > repositories`, try updating it there cause that's where it pulls your buildscript (plugins) from

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrais.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: Now I added mavenCentral() under buildscript and allproject repositories- but the same result

Comment: do you still have the same error? are you sure you're modifying the right `build.gradle`?

Comment: yes i have modified the right build.gradle

Comment: I've updated the answer, sorry for confusing you with a wrong solution :(

Comment: Where should I place this?org.jetbrais.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72

Comment: I have corrected the typo - but still the same error comes

Comment: So what I've posted in my answer is the original version with typo. You have to use this one `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72` which has `jetbrais` replaced with `jetbrains`